# Cryptic Family Reunion: Bumper Crop!

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues

The answer to this puzzle is a list of [<s>ten</s>  FIFTEEN](https://youtu.be/I48hr8HhDv0?t=43) thematically related words or proper names or phrases. Each of these is clued cryptically, and the theme is to be determined. Since the definition part of a cryptic clue would give away the theme, these cryptic clues use a family member (e.g., mom, sister) to stand in for the definition part of the clue. So for example, if the theme of the puzzle were chemical elements, "Sister picking at nit" would clue "tin". I hope you enjoy!

1. Pleasant to eat out sans facemask with daughter (10)
2. Uncle Ed buried by Dad (6)
3. Abuela provides spicy mole over nacho chip (5)
4. Sister's first son swallowed toasted almond (10)
5. Mom's heart overcomes misplaced anger for Dad (6)
6. Wife sporting no bra? Cool. (9)
7. Pappy and gin neat, on the rocks, with dash of water (9)
8. Aunt Sal failed to complete one requirement, in hindsight (7)
9. Niece's first riddle a bad pun, second cringeworthy (6)
10. Brother pushes eastern currency in backwards America (8)
11. Switzerland supports progressive Saudi father (7)
12. Son in return from demilitarized zone (4)
13. Nonna's gnocchi not too filling (8)
14. Cousin's ego bruised over odd tart (5)
15. Daughter, traveling thus around Guyana, miserably (10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are

> Citrus fruits.

1. Pleasant to eat out sans facemask with daughter (10)

> CLEMENT+(-d)INE

2. Uncle Ed buried by Dad (6)

> PAP(ED)A

3. Abuela provides spicy mole over nacho chip (5)

> LEMO*+N_

4. Sister's first son swallowed toasted almond (10)

> CA(LAMOND*)IN

5. Mom's heart overcomes misplaced anger for Dad (6)

> _O_+RANGE*

6. Wife sporting no bra? Cool. (9)

> OROBLANCO*

7. Pappy and gin neat, on the rocks, with dash of water (9)

> TANG(_ER)INE*

8. Aunt Sal failed to complete one requirement, in hindsight (7)

> SA(-l)+(TSUM+A)<

9. Niece's first riddle a bad pun, second cringeworthy (6)

> R_+A+NPU*+_R_

10. Brother pushes eastern currency in backwards America (8)

> A(MANAT)SU<

11. Switzerland supports progressive Saudi father (7)

> SUDA(CH)I*

12. Son in return from demilitarized zone (4)

> _LIME_<

13. Nonna's gnocchi not too filling (8)

> _CHI NOT TO_

14. Cousin's ego bruised over odd tart (5)

> E(T_R_)OG*

15. Daughter, traveling thus around Guyana, miserably (10)

> H(YUGANA*)TSU*

Comment: Crushed in detail! The wordplay on #7 was as-intended. Great job jafe!